# Can I create a Redshift cluster in Terraform AND add an additional user to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get terraform set up to where I can have an array of cluster parameters and then do a for_each in a redshift module to create them all like so:

```
    for_each = local.env[var.tier][var.region].clusters
    source  = "terraform-aws-modules/redshift/aws"

    cluster_identifier    = "${each.value.name}"
    allow_version_upgrade = true
    node_type             = "dc2.large"
    number_of_nodes       = 2

    database_name          = "${each.value.database}"
    master_username        = "${each.value.admin_user}"
    create_random_password = false
    master_password        = "${each.value.admin_password}"

    encrypted   = true
    kms_key_arn = xxxxx

    enhanced_vpc_routing   = false
    vpc_security_group_ids = xxxxxx
    subnet_ids             = xxxxxx

    publicly_accessible = true

    iam_role_arns = xxxxxx

    # Parameter group
    parameter_group_name = xxxxxx

    # Subnet group
    create_subnet_group = false
    subnet_group_name   = xxxxxx

    # Maintenance
    preferred_maintenance_window = "sat:01:00-sat:01:30"

    # Backup Details
    automated_snapshot_retention_period = 30
    manual_snapshot_retention_period = -1
}
```

But I also want to add an additional user aside from the admin user to each of these clusters. I am struggling to find a way to do this in terraform. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Can try to use TF [Redshift Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/brainly/redshift/latest/docs) which allows you to create `redshift_user`.
2. Use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) to invoke [JDBC, Python or ODBC tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-to-cluster.html) that will create your user using SQL commands.